# Overriding lock/power button in android devices

Tags: android, callback, android-button, keyevent

I would like to know if its possible to override power button in android?

I read a lot of posts in Stack Overflow, some saying it's possible and some saying it's not ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420927/disable-power-button-or-resume-full-screen-in-android-toddler-app)).

What I am trying to achieve is that - when user is using my app he needs to press the lock/power button 5 times to lock the screen. I dont want to override the swtich off functionality only the lock one.

Is there anyway to fetch power button callback?

I tried WakeLock and disabled the keyguard but it does'nt serve my pupose.

I tried out below code from Shink link posted in comments section below:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        // do what you want with the power button
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "down", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        // do what you want with the power button
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
   return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

The toast msg are only shown if I hold the power button for like 2 secs. why is that?

Is it possible override power button functionality which locks the screen? Or is there any other way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Even I was looking for a solution for the same problem but couldn't find anything related to it. Ultimately I had to change my course of the application. Though you can capture the event of Screen ON and Screen OFF. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263661/how-to-know-if-the-user-has-pressed-power-key-twice-or-thrice-continuously-outsi

Comment: @Shink it sure is something new that i found out. Thanks for that. But it doesnt help me in my case

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable POWER_BUTTON for security purpose. It runs with broadcast/subscriber patterns... :(