# Android: Overriding the power button in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, keyevent

I'm working on a thing where I need to override the power button in a Fragment when pressed. I did this successfully, however, the screen turns off when the power button is pressed.

I did a quick search and came across a few posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619950/overriding-lock-power-button-in-android-devices), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886466/overriding-the-power-button-in-android), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888250/stop-the-screen-locking-when-power-button-is-pressed). Some say it's doable and others say it's not. My question is that is this even doable? If so, any idea how to go about this?

Comment: You have to keep screen on using WindowManager flags, as power button key event will only be called when its long pressed.

Comment: @AbdulKawee I tried it in a couple of ways (one of them is mentioned in my question). It didn't work. I suspect that it prevents screen from going to sleep on t's own, not override the power button functionality.

Comment: Check the answer i posted.

Comment: @AbdulKawee Testing your code now.

Comment: For security reasons we cannot override the functionality of a power button short click i.e lock screen but we can detect the long click of button

Comment: @AbdulKawee Is there a way to prevent screen lock/sleep from affecting my app(if it was just for only a few seconds)?

Comment: How does it effect your app?? Tell me , may be there is a solution for your problem

Comment: @AbdulKawee I'm using it in a fragment and as far as I know (please correct me if I'm wrong) locking the screen would destroy or pause the fragment. If that's the case, I suspect that I need to specify somewhere to pause the fragment on screen lock.

Comment: No i don't think that fragment will be destroyed, lock screen will cause you activity to pause, just save states there and in onResume() restore those states it will work for you.

Comment: Fragments will have problem when screen orientation is changed, thats because activity is destroyed and is recreated at that time

Comment: @AbdulKawee Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to prevent screen from locking

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

While using in fragment

```
getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

Use a BroadcastReceiver and listen for the `android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF` or `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` which is sent when power button is pressed (and screen is on). What i think is that overriding the power button is not possible , because of security issues.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not advisable. However you can write a broadcast receiver and then the screen gets locked, wake it up using AlarmManager. Below is the code.

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if ((intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))) {

PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "TEST");
wakeLock.acquire();

AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent inten = new Intent(context,NewActivity.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, inten, 0);
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,  100, pi);
}
}   

// Finish your WakeLock HERE. call this method after U put the activity in front or when u exit from the new activity.
public void finishWakeLocker(){
if (wakeLock != null) 
wakeLock.release();  
}
```

Comment: This code only awakes the device when it sleeps, it doesn't override power button.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot override the power button functionality however you can prevent system from showing dialog on long press of a power button using following.

```
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if(!hasFocus) {
           Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
            sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
        }
    }
```